# iOS: How to use decodable for a model class with variable of type a protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols, decodable

**Question:** There is a model class that conforms to Decodable, this model has a variable of type someProtocol. But compiler gives an error,

**Compiler error**

```
Type 'MyModel' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
Protocol requires initializer 'init(from:)' with type 'Decodable'
Cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because 'SomeProtocol' does not conform to 
'Decodable'
```

Code Snippet

```
class MyModel: Decodable {
var name: String?
var employee: SomeProtocol?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
    case employee
}

} // Enf of class MyModel

protocol SomeProtocol {
 var employeeName: String ? { get }
}
```

Comment: You cannot type `employee` as a protocol. To be automatically Decodable, all of MyModel's properties must be of a type that adopts Decodable. As the error message tells you, if you want to write an `init(from:)` to conform to Decodable, go right ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]
Hi,
So I guess this question was valid and after some searching, I was able to solve.
 MyModel class cannot have a protocol type, there should be a concrete type class that inherits protocol. Object is now decoded with nested other model objects too.

**Corrected Above code**

```
class MyModel: Decodable {
var name: String?
var employee: OtherModel?

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
case name = "DepartmentName"
case employee
}

} // End of class MyModel

class OtherModel: SomeProtocol {
var employeeName: String?
}

protocol SomeProtocol: Decodable {
 var employeeName: String? { get }
}
```

**Note:** 
Didn't need init(from decoder: Decoder)
 in this case.

Comment: Yes but you are loosing the avantage of your `protocol`. You are now using **inheritance**.

Comment: Yes, Kevin, you are right? But I cannot use the pure protocol as variable since the compiler doesn't know how to synthesize or decode this type. So yes this object becomes tied to another object.